# Is it possible to access Organization-Scoped Artifact Feeds using the Azure Devops API?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I need to find the ID of a Feed to use with the Artifact resource of the Azure DevOps API. I currently use this URL to view all Artifact feeds in my Organization.

```
https://feeds.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/packaging/feeds?api-version=6.0-preview.1
```

This returns all Project-Scoped Feeds, but not the Organization-Scoped Feeds. I've tried using the link below to access one with no avail, it will always tell me the provided ID does not exist.

```
https://feeds.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/packaging/feeds/{feedId}?api-version=6.0-preview.1
```

So my question is: Is there any way to access information/packages from an Organization-Scoped Feed using the DevOps API?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there any way to access information/packages from an Organization-Scoped Feed using the DevOps API?

The answer is yes.

You could **remove** the **`{project}`** from your REST API URL:

```
https://feeds.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/packaging/feeds?api-version=6.0-preview.1
```

Or

```
https://feeds.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/packaging/feeds/{feedId}?api-version=6.0-preview.1
```

My test result:

[image]